# Is there a difference between Thunder, Force, and Bludgeoning damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-types

Inspired by [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/92798/32508), is there a precedent for when to use Thunder vs Force vs Bludgeoning damage when designing monsters, traps, or spells? The damage types as is are very similar, and it can be a bit difficult to differentiate between effects.

Comment: Related: [Would a concussive bomb deal Sonic damage or something else?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30849/would-a-concussive-bomb-deal-sonic-damage-or-something-else)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As I was writing my question, I realized that my clarifications and self research were becoming an answer of their own:

#### Bludgeoning

Definition on PHB p. 196:

> Blunt force attacks—hammers, falling, constriction, and the like—deal bludgeoning damage.

Caused by blunt **physical** impacts or weight by a tangible thing. Examples:

- Maces, clubs, sling stones, rocks, or fists (or launched items, like in *Catapult*)
- Being crushed or squeezed (e.g. *Maximillian's Earthen Grasp*, *Bones of the Earth*, or *Bigby's Hand: Grasping hand*)
- Falling from a height and colliding with the ground
- Objects dropped onto a creature (e.g. *Transmute Rock*, *Storm of Vengeance*'s hail, "Rocks fall, everyone dies")
- Impact with water, or the result of being pushed around by water, particularly via spells (e.g. Monk's *Water Whip*, and *Tidal Wave*)
- Impact with objects or the sheer force in a whirlpool or whirlwind (e.g. *Whirlwind*, *Control Water*, *Storm Sphere*

#### Force

Definition on PHB p. 196:

> Force is pure magical energy focused into a damaging form. Most effects that deal force damage are spells, including *magic missile* and *spiritual weapon*.

Caused by a strike of **concentrated or tangible magical energy**. Alternatively, caused by ending a turn in an object or creature as an incorporeal creature, or similarly having a mishap while teleporting (which could be construed as the same thing). Examples:

- Concentrated energy (*Magic Missile*, *Eldritch Blast*, *Disintegrate*)
- Strike of tangible magical energy (*Spiritual Weapon*, *Bigby's Hand*, *Mordenkainen's Sword*)
- Occupying a space while incorporeal (Specter, Wraith, Shadow Demon)
- *Teleport* mishaps

#### Thunder

Definition on PHB p. 196:

> A concussive burst of sound, such as the effect of the *thunderwave* spell, deals thunder damage.

Caused by a **sonic boom**, or otherwise extremely loud sound, representing the concussive force and damaging effect on the ear. This is a very rare damage type but can also be created by arbitrary elemental effect spells. Examples:

- Sonic boom (*Thunderwave*, *Shatter*, *Storm of Vengeance*)
- Arbitrary damage type spells (*Chromatic Orb*, *Glyph of Warding*)