# Would simulacrum be affected by ageing?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, simulacrum

Since it is a spell with a duration "instantaneous", the spell ends after it is cast and the copy created will remain there. And it says:

> It appears to be the same as the original, but it has only one-half of the real creature’s levels or Hit Dice (and the appropriate hit points, feats, skill ranks, and special abilities for a creature of that level or HD).

So I assume there's no hard time limit for how long a simulacrum can stay there after it is created.

Then, let's say a lich somehow falls in love with a human, and that human dies by ageing after half a century. To memorize the lover, this lich creates a simulacrum of its lover. Will this human simulacrum also be affected by ageing later on as the original would, or would it stay as-is forever with the lich?

(I see the creation is considered a construct in 5e, but it seems not the case for 3.5e (it looks like the original's type will be used). It makes sense to be a construct, though. [Is the 'copy' from Simulacrum a humanoid or a construct?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165084/is-the-copy-from-simulacrum-a-humanoid-or-a-construct))

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121855/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Okay, so it does age since the type is duplicated. Close this question now.